# postman collection and env disappeared

Tags: postman

postman after update, collection and env disappeared.
[image]

And when click workspaces,there is only sign in.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Postman deprecated the Scratchpad, so if you want to continue using collections you will need to sign in as that feature is now only available with an account.  You should have seen the following dialogue during the upgrade process.

[image]

The Lightweight client will allow  you to make requests, but it won't run a collection.

You can get access to copy your data in the Lightweight client through Settings -> Data -> Export, but you won't be able to run them as collections without creating an account.